# Dock! Fullscreen games and then do you want into a new app

Tags: plank

I'll recorded this issue or my badness ...

How can I quick switch to a new app without changing desktop or closing all? <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> is not really an solution.

Heres the unlisted Video and sorry for my bad english ...
https://youtu.be/vo5AsTwnYhQ

Greetings from Austria (no kangoroos)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you are trying to switch from a fullscreen app to another app aren't you? If it is the case, the Alt+tab would not help you because when an app goes fullscreen the os automatically moves it to another space but alt+tab is a keyboard shrotcut to swtitch applications on the current space only.

In this case what you want to achieve is to switch the space, and for this reason you have to use **Super+Tab** keyboard shortcut. Another options are **Super+a**, **Super+s** and **Super+w**

Super = windows like key on your windows keyboard or Cmd if you are on a mac. By default if you press only the Super key it triggers  a command that shows available keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: but this is not a smooth usabillity, thos is horrible ... then Elementary OS is for people who start a browser and not more :(

Comment: I am not the designer of the eOS but my opinion is that using different keyboard shortcuts then the ones you have habits to use doesn't make it less smoother and definitely I use it with lot more applications at one and the same time and do not found any troubles switching between them. Again it si just a matter of habbits that can be changed. If my answer resolves your issue, please make it correct

Comment: your shortcuts are a "way" but not that what i mean, i had to create a new desktop to start a app from my dock? thats a longer way, why the hell should i make a new desktop to start a new app from the dock :(  it can be simple with 1 button but not in elementary O_o

Comment: You like it or not when using eOS  **if you are in fullscreen, you cannot use the dock**. So if you have an application in fullscreen mode in order to start another one you have to go to another space or if you use **Multitasking view** (Super+s) you can drag another application into a space that has a fullscreen app on it already and by using **Alt+Tab** you can switch between the applications.And when a nonfullscreen app is selected you can use the dock to start another one no matter that there is a fullscreen app behind.To change that you can put an issue on
 https://github.com/elementary